# R Problems using haven::as_factor

Tags: r, dplyr, r-haven

The data has answers of 1, 2 and NA for FP. I am trying to set up the data for a ggplot box plot, and need the factors so it can use FP for the x values in the plot to split them into separate plots. I then want to rename to NAs to OM, and ideally rename 1 and 2 to character values as well.

```
c_plot <- dataset %>%
  select(XCD, FP) %>%
  filter(XCD > 0) %>%
  haven::as_factor(FP, levels = "labels") %>%
  mutate(FP = ifelse(is.na(FP, OM, FP)) %>%
```

The error is:

```
Error in force(ordered) : object 'FTPT' not found
Error:
! Arguments in `...` must be used.
x Problematic argument:
* ..1 = FP
```

How do I get it to correctly produce the data I need?

Comment: you may need `... %>% mutate(FP = haven::as_factor(FP, levels = "labels")) %>%...`.  IN the next step, you are using OM column in ifelse whereas you selected only XCD, FP, thus it may not work.  along with `is.na(FP)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your data it's hard to tell exactly what's going wrong, but you could try something like `mutate(abc = haven::as_factor(col_name))` e.g.:

```r
iris %>% 
  mutate(abc = haven::as_factor(Sepal.Length))

#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species abc
# 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa 5.1
# 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa 4.9
# 3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa 4.7
# 4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa 4.6
# 5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa   5
```

Also, the last line should look like this (note the placement of the parentheses)

```r
  mutate(FP = ifelse(is.na(FP), OM, FP))
```

Comment: @akrun good point. Addressed.

Comment: The perils of multitasking in Teams meetings! XCD is a numeric vector. FP is coded responses to a survey question, imported from spss, hence needing haven.

Comment: This worked fine once I put "OM" with quotes in the ifelse statement.

Comment: I have now gone to plot the data and discovered that instead of the labels, it's converting all the 1s to 5s, and the 2s to 6s, even when I specify level = "labels". Trying to use case when to change them to the labels fails due ! LHS of case 1 (`5`) must be a logical vector, not a double vector.

Comment: When using `haven::as.factor`, I get "Error: 'as.factor' is not an exported object from 'namespace:haven'".